# Just noticed tons of my songs are missing from my iTunes Library ... what gives?

Tags: itunes, music

I have hundreds of CDs burned to my iTunes Library, and lots of individual songs I bought from the iTunes Store over the years.

All legal.

I have all of my music on my iPhone and that's where I listen to it mostly.

I just noticed in the iTunes Library, there are tons of songs missing.

Here are some screen shots (below) ... every song with a "!" icon next to it is missing, not on the hard drive.

There are no other problems or missing files on my MacBook.

What gives?

In some cases ... David Bowie "Tonight", Pearl Jam "Ten", for example ... the entire album is gone.

I'm not an Apple Music subscriber, but I did try the three month trial when it first came out.

Did Apple do some kind of "sync with Apple Music" on my iTunes Library which caused songs to get replaced with their copies and, in some cases, removed?

Any ideas what happened here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure why but you should be able to redownload them either way.

Comment: @JBis Is there a way to get the songs from my iPhone and put them back in the iTunes Library?

Comment: Please upload the screenshot directly into your post (instead of linking to imgur.com). Also, how do you sync your library between the iPhone and the computer running iTunes?

Comment: @nohillside Added screenshots to post, thanks.  I sync music by plugging my iPhone into the MacBook via USB/Lightning cable.  I have not synced my music in a long time, maybe a year or longer.  Looked at iTunes on MacBook to make some playlists, and noticed this missing songs issue.

Comment: Are the files also deleted from the Finder?

Comment: If you right click on a missing track it will show the path it is looking for - what is it and in Prefernces what is the default path?

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the help -- when I do that, it shows me the folder where the rest of the songs from that album are, but the missing song files are not there.